# Group Policy not being applied because of mysteriously missing file

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

A single machine on my network won't apply ANY policies because it cannot retrieve `\\my.domain.net\SysVol\my.domain.net\Policies\{hash}\gpt.ini` . The file is visible under `\\controller.my.domain.net\SysVol\my.domain.net\Policies\{hash}\gpt.ini` on this machine, but I can't see it under \my.domain.net\SysVol\

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Comment: @Nixphoe \\my.domain.net\SysVol\my.domain.net\Policies\{hash}\gpt.ini

Comment: As Shane said, you *should* be able to access it from \\my.domain.net\sysvol. Can you access it from \\controller.my.domain.net on the computer with the issue? If you can access it through the server name, it sounds like you have a DNS issue on that computer as the \\my.domain.net should point to any of your domain controllers (IE \\controller.my.domain.net)

Comment: Yes, it's visible from `\\controller.my.domain.net`. DNS is fine (as far as I know, how would I test it?) and this problem exists only on this one machine, of a network of about 70 boxes.

Comment: From your problem machine: Try running through releasing, renewing your IP address, make sure you don't have a static IP address for your DNS server. Then do an `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by an `ipconfig /registerdns`. Then try an `nslookup` from the machine.

Comment: No problems with DNS.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong. It was a DNS problem. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Let us know more about what the issue was so future guests can learn

Answer (score 4):

`\\my.domain.net\sysvol\` is the correct access point for group policy clients - stick it in an explorer window and see.

What errors are you seeing that indicate that it's not successfully applying policy?

Verify that the desired GPOs are linked to an object that the computer account is under, and that the computer is in the security filters for those GPOs.

Check `rsop.msc` to verify which policy the system's current settings are from; if any come from the `Default Domain Policy` or any other domain GPO, then you know that it's working; the event log should be a good source of troubleshooting information, too.

Comment: It complains about not being able to read a file (which, for some reason that is beyond me is not visible on this machine, but is on the one right next to it) and it says it won't apply GP settings until it can read this one specific file. I thought it was suppost to be `\\controller.my.domain.net` because the file is readable on `\\controller.my.domain.net` but not `\\my.domain.net`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Shane stated in his answer (RSOP can show you what settings are being applied and by which GPO) it would be useful to run Group Policy Results from the GPMC to get more in depth GPO information, such as which polices are being denied (and why) as well as which policies are being applied (which can be determined with RSOP as Shane stated), user and computer group membership, the last time of policy application, errors related to policy application, and events related to Group Policy application.

Comment: No policies are being applied because of this one file that it can't read. So, I guess the problem is that it can't read this file.

Comment: Try setting this GPO setting in the GPO that applies to the client computer (or alternately, setting it in the registry of the affected client) listed here: http://www.boyce.us/gp/gpcontent.asp?ID=39

Answer (score 0):

Your domain `\\my.domain.net\SysVol\` should point to one of your DCs. It sounds like you're having some kind of DNS issue from your single Mahcine.

From your problem machine: Try running through `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`, make sure you don't have a static IP address for your DNS server. Then do an `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by an `ipconfig /registerdns`. Then try an `nslookup` from the machine to see what kind of results you get.